# Get list of all svg-files in Angular assets-folder

Tags: angular, assets, filelist

I've got the following problem. I want to register all svg-files from my asset folder in my angular-app.
But I don't know, if it is possible to read the whole folder-content by angular, because it is client-running.

Does anybody has an idea about this?

Regards
Elias

P.S. As a workaround I would run a deployment-script, which writes all the files in a json-file, so I can read them from that file. But I don't want to do this...

Comment: Maintain list of assets in JSON file is the preferred way, as for as i know.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya thanks. For notice, I'll try to implement a pre-compile-script, that creates a JSON-file of all assets. Seems like there aren't any other solutions.

Comment: Yes. you are right. we don't have any other solution apart from this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some security reasons we should not / can not access local file from javascript.

In your case, I suggest you create an API and should store your files in backend folder and return to client list files. This is the way I done in my project.

You can create ASP.NET Web API as

```
[Route("listSVGfiles")]
List<string> getSVGfiles() {

}
```